# Kubernetes Rollout Drop Old Pods When New Pods Are Not Fully Ready

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm using the `kubectl rollout` command to update my deployment. But since my project is a NodeJS Project. The `npm run start` will take some take(a few seconds before the application is actually running.) But Kubernetes will drop the old pods immediately after the `npm run start` is executed.

For example,

```
kubectl logs -f my-app

> my app start
> nest start
```

The Kubernetes will drop the old pods now. However, it will take another 10 seconds until

```
Application is running on: http://[::1]:5274
```

which means my service is actually up.

I'd like to know whether there is a way to modify this like waiting some more time before kubernetes drop the old pods.

My docker file:

```
FROM node:14 AS builder
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY protos ./protos/
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=16384
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
# FROM node:14
# COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
# COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
# COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
# COPY --from=builder /app/protos ./protos
EXPOSE 5273
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Spec for my kubernetes yaml file:

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: image
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "8Gi"
            cpu: "10"
          requests:
            memory: "8Gi"
            cpu: "10"
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /api/Health
            port: 5274
          initialDelaySeconds: 180
          periodSeconds: 80
          timeoutSeconds: 20
          failureThreshold: 2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5274
        - containerPort: 5900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a startup probe on your container. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/applications/application-health.html . Pods don't count as "ready" until all of their containers have passed their startup (and readiness) checks.

And during a deployment the scheduler counts non-ready pods as "unavailable" for things like the "maxUnavailable" setting of the deployment. Thus the scheduler won't keep shutting down working pods until new pods are ready for traffic. (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/applications/deployments/deployment-strategies.html)

As an additional benefit, services won't route traffic to non-ready pods, so they won't receive any traffic until the containers have passed their startup probes.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my yaml as advised.